# How can a join the results of an xpath?

Tags: xpath

I have an xpath that selects the correct 'section' of text, but it gives me a long list of items.

The structure is something like (changes on different parts of the site)

xpath:  `RID = P.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "phml msg-body")][contains(@id, "message1")])//text()').getall()`

```
<div>
          formatting "stuff i do want" formatting
     <br>
          formatting "more stuff i want" formatting
<div>
```

From my xpath i get about 10 entries (depends again on the formatting of the site) where i only want one.

Is there a way to get an output like `"stuff i do want more stuff i want"` which I append to a list, and my list should have length of 1.

My current expath gives me

````
'\r\n', '\r\n', '  ', ', ' stuff i do want', '  ', '\r\n', '\r\n', '\r\n', '\r\n', '\r\n', '\r\n', '\r\n', "more stuff i want", '  ', '\r\n', '\r\n', '\r\n', '\r\n', '\r\n', '\r\n', '\r\n', '\r\n', '\r\n', '\r\n ```
````

Comment: What's your current XPath attempt? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62759516/edit) the question and do not add it as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's a typo but you have an extra `)` in your XPath expression. It should be :

```
//div[contains(@class, "phml msg-body")][contains(@id, "message1")]//text()
```

Assuming you're using `scrappy`, to get your expected output, you can use `normalize-space` to ignore whitespace nodes. Then use `.join`, and `.strip()` to remove leading and trailing white spaces (the `formatting` you're talking about). So the following expression should work :

```
RID = " ".join([el.get().strip() for el in response.xpath("//div[contains(@class, "phml msg-body")][contains(@id, "message1")]//text()[normalize-space()]")])
```

If needed, you can add `.replace("\r\n", "")` after `.strip()` for a final cleaning.

Another way of doing it with `normalize-space` on the `div` element :

```
RID = normalize-space(//div[contains(@class, "phml msg-body")][contains(@id, "message1")]).get()
```

Or with `concat` (assuming the div of your sample data corresponds to the div of your XPath expression) :

```
RID = normalize-space(concat(//div[contains(@class, "phml msg-body")][contains(@id, "message1")]/text()[1],//div[contains(@class, "phml msg-body")][contains(@id, "message1")]/text()[2])).get()
```

Comment: Thankyou so much! I got it to work with an adaptation of your code. And yes, there was a typo.

Comment: The code that got me the content i wanted was `RID = P.xpath('normalize-space(//div[contains(@class, "phml msg-body")][contains(@id, "message1")])').getall()`